# Run node.js server file using apache default port

Tags: node.js, apache, client-server, wamp, wampserver

I have this node.js server file:

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler),
io = require('socket.io').listen(app),
fs = require('fs'),

app.listen(80);

function handler (req,res){

    fs.readFile("/client.html"), function(err, data) {  
        if (err) {

           console.log(err);
           res.writeHead(500);
           return res.end('Error loading client');
        }

        res.writeHead(200);
        res.end(data);
    });
}
```

is there a way to make this node.js file run automatically through the apache default port number when a client tries to connect without having to run it through the cmd ?

Comment: I don't think there is a way if I understood correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> without having to run it through the cmd

Short answer: not quite. Think of this node.js file as creating a server on a par with Apache.

The script creates a server `.createServer()` and then tells it to listen to port 80 `.listen(80)`.

Since socket.io is bound to this node server (and can't just be plugged in to Apache) you will have to execute the script (run it through the cmd) to be able to utilize it.

That being said:
I'm sure one could make a daemon (a background program) out of the node server; thus firing it up automatically on system start. If you then specify to run it on port xxxx you could tell Apache to map this port into its own local space (its folders). On a local machine this instruction would look like this: `ProxyPass /app http://127.0.0.1:xxxx/`
There would be two servers running on one machine; and Apache's `http://127.0.0.1/app` would redirect to the node server (listening to xxxx).

I would not advise to go down that rabbit hole just yet. To start having fun with socket.io on windows just create a batch file with the command to run your server: `node [path/to/your/server_file.js]` for ease of use. Expand your node script. And stop using Apache. (Express is a nice module to use node for web content...)